# Trouble with gem install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm trying to install rails on a new Mac (OS X Mavericks) and I keep getting the error listed below.

I ran both with and without the `sudo` command:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
Fetching: i18n-0.6.5.gem (100%)

Successfully installed i18n-0.6.5
Fetching: rails-4.0.1.gem (100%) 

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `hexdigest' for #<OpenSSL::Digest:0x00000109da3018
```

I've installed and reinstalled my different versions of ruby as well as reinstalling `openssl`.  Nothing seems to work and I've found nothing about the error when googling.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If you're using multiple versions of Ruby, something like RVM would be helpful for managing them. What version of ruby are you using when you get this error? `ruby -v`

Comment: Got the same exact problem. Please tell me if you get something!